# Insert strings to strings array c

Tags: c, arrays

I need something simple but don't know why it's so hard with c (my background is java), need to input strings to string array in c, here my code:

```
    int n;  
printf("Please enter number of words \n");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
char *a=(int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Enter word \n");            
    scanf_s("%s", a[i]);// <--line gives error
}
```

example:

```
Please enter number of words
3
Enter word
aaa
Enter word
bbb
Enter word
ccc
```

the array would look like: `[aaa][bbb][ccc]`

Comment: Please be more specific with your input and expected output

Comment: Please read the [man page for `scanf_s`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017). You are using `scanf_s` with `%s` specifier incorrectly. *"Unlike `scanf` ... `scanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable."* Even better, don't use Microsoft's supposed "safer" functions, use the standard ones.

Comment: @Grantly I added example

Comment: @WeatherVane please show me how as answer

Comment: The linked manpage shows how to use it.

Comment: Allocating a character buffer with `sizeof(int)` makes zero sense where. How many characters do you want? That's `n`. How long are your words? You don't know, so you need to allocate a very generous buffer or you'll overflow it. Try `1024` or `65535`. If you need an array of arrays, you'll need to structure that differently.

Comment: @tadman let's say words that no longer than 10 charachres

Comment: why there is no answer for this yet, with java that's very basic thing to do, is it so complicated with c?

Comment: The line: `char *a=(int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));` allocates enough space to hold n integers.  That's not going to be enough space to hold n strings of indeterminate length.

Comment: The C way is to allocate as you go, or allocate a sufficiently large enough buffer to hold everything and then split it up into parts by NUL terminating segments of it, then create an array of pointers to those parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int n;  

  printf("Please enter number of words \n");
  if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid number");
  else if (n <= 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "number is not > 0");
  else {
    char ** a = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    char word[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf("Enter word (max length 15)\n");            
      if (scanf("%15s", word) != 1) {
        fprintf("EOF");
        return -1;
      }
      a[i] = strdup(word);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      printf("[%s]", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall as.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter number of words 
3
Enter word (max length 15)
aze
Enter word (max length 15)
qsd
Enter word (max length 15)
wxc
[aze][qsd][wxc]
```

---

Note that in remark you compare C and Java, Java is an object language, not C, compare Java and C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Please enter number of words" << endl;

  int n;

  if (!(cin >> n))
    cerr << "invalid number" << endl;
  else if (n <= 0)
    cerr << "number is not > 0" << endl;
  else {
    vector<string> a;
    string word;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << "Enter word" << endl;

      if (!(cin >> word)) {
        cerr << "EOF" << endl;
        return -1;
      }
      a.push_back(word);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout << '[' << a[i] << ']';
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall as.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter number of words
3
Enter word
aze
Enter word
qsd
Enter word
wxc
[aze][qsd][wxc]
```